# Call an external app on windows phone 8.1 runtime(not silverlight) xaml c# application

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying launch an external app sending one parameter from my application. Anyone knows one way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Pleas explain what you are trying to do, aside from "launch an external app". What app? Why? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried so far? What is not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730280/windows-phone-8-1-how-to-launch-an-installed-app-from-my-app/34487753#34487753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-emailandaccounts:///"));
```

This goes to "email and accounts" settings. You can find URI schemes for other system apps here: [Reserved file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Reservedprotocolnames)

There are also some new options for wp 8.1:

```
ms-settings-workplace
ms-settings-proximity
ms-settings-nfctransactions
ms-settings-networkprofileupdate
ms-settings-notifications
ms-settings-camera
ms-settings-uicctoolkit
ms-battery
ms-wallet
```

You can also **[register your app for a URI association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)**  and pass parameters to it:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("myapp:///parameters"));
```

Comment: Hi, Will it work for windows 8.1 apps? I am trying to open another app but couldn't. I tried `await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("myapp:///parameters"));` but gives some exception. I don't know how to register app for a URI assocation in windows 8.1 apps.

Answer (score 1):

You have only two ways to launch an external application

1. Launch registered file type
2. Launch registered URI scheme

You can find additional details at the MSDN: [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi guy. Thank you for your answer. But i want launch a app without pass a file type. I want launch a specific app like photos and when i exit of this app come back for my app. Thank you again!

Comment: If you want to open the image library there is a specific way to do it.

Comment: hi, what is this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730280/windows-phone-8-1-how-to-launch-an-installed-app-from-my-app/34487753#34487753