# Windows Phone 8.1 - add URL to launch phone app to e-mail

Tags: url, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I created a windows phone 8.1 app that is deployed to my phone. I want to launch the app from a url in my e-mail or in a document attachment? Is this possible. I have created a uri association for the app already.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message? What is the uri you have registered for? Please provide more details.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037300/call-an-external-app-on-windows-phone-8-1-runtimenot-silverlight-xaml-c-sharp